# Compare two separate JSONs

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a resultant json from an intermediate stage as following

```
a=[{
    "ID": "1201",
    "SubID": "S1201",
    "Information": {
        "Name": "Kim",
        "Age": "41"
    }
}, {
    "ID": "1433",
    "subID": "G1433",
    "Information": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Age": "32"
    }
}]
```

I have another json that needs to compared with the above json

```
c= [{
            "ID": "1201",
            "SubID": "S1201"
        },
        {
            "ID": "3211",
            "subID": "G3211"
        }
    ]
```

since the json object(a) in my intermediate result is present in another json(c). I want to retain only the json object which is being repeated.

```
expected output:

[{
    "ID": "1201",
    "SubID": "S1201",
    "Information": {
        "Name": "Kim",
        "Age": "41"
    }
}]
```

I'm not clear on what the approach to proceed with in achieving the same. Please guide me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Neither of these are JSON but Python dicts. Once you read and parsed the files, the resulting data is independent of JSON.

Comment: I do not know much about python but I would recommend using a for loop and checking if the value exists in the array. I think that there should be a function for that like: PHP array_key_exists. If it doesn't then delete the array.

Comment: @Robbie found a python equivalent has_key which will serve the purpose
thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
ids = [e['ID'] for e in c]
repeated = [e for e in a if e['ID'] in ids]
print(repeated)
```

Comment: Or `[d1 for d1 in a for d2 in c if d1.get("ID") == d2.get("ID") is not None]`

Comment: even `zip` works for this example although it's highly unlikely that it would suffice for OP's real data